# Need help in determining pre-post COVID-19 Medicine 'Average Usage'

Tags: python, pandas

Here our objective is to get 'Average Tablet usage' by User and by Product based on the distance between days. My dataset is like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Patient': ['John','Smith','John','Smith','John','Smith','John','Smith','John','Smith','John','Smith'],
                  'Drug': ['brufen','tylenol','brufen','tylenol','brufen','tylenol','tylenol','brufen','tylenol','brufen','tylenol','brufen'],
                   'Date': [20200101, 20200102, 20200105, 20200108, 20200113, 20200110,20200120, 20200125, 20200124, 20200126, 20200126, 20200127],
                   'Tablets': [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]})
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
df.head()
```

The result I am looking like below...Your help is much appreciated.

```
df_result = pd.DataFrame({'Patient': ['John','Smith','John','Smith'],
                  'Drug': ['brufen','tylenol','brufen','tylenol'],
                   'Average_Days_Distance_In_Usage': [6, 4, 3, 1]})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `groupby()` and `transform()` with `shift()` to get the days for each row. Then, just group by patient and drug.

```
df = df.sort_values(["Patient","Drug","Date"]).copy(deep=True)
df["Days"] = df.groupby(["Patient","Drug"])['Date'].transform(lambda x: x- x.shift()).dt.days
result_df = df.groupby(["Patient","Drug"])["Days"].mean().reset_index()
```